# Fluent ribbon tab color

Tags: wpf, fluent-ribbon

Hello I am making an *Edit* tab in fluent ribbon that I would like the color to be different when it shows up. I currently have it showing and disappearing like it is supposed to. However, I cannot seem to have it show the correct color while it isn't selected, but when I select the tab it then is the correct color. Below are screen shots.

```
<fluentRibbon:RibbonTabItem Header="Edit" 
                      Visibility="{Binding IsInEditMode,
                                  Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                      Background="Magenta"
                      BorderBrush="Magenta"
                      ActiveTabBackground="Magenta">
</fluentRibbon:RibbonTabItem>
```

Not Showing Tab Items:

Showing Tab item without color:

[image: Showing Tab item without color]

selected and the
Showing correct color:
[image: Showing correct color]

Comment: From your screenshot 1 & 2, where do you want to implement this "_I cannot seem to have it show the correct color while it isn't selected_". Is the second one in _non-selected_ state? If yes, it is NOT showing any color just as u want

Comment: I have edited this the first one now is where edit isnt selected the second one is selected

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, like your **Background** property would be commented out.
For FluentRibbon version 10.0.4, looks like **Background** overrides **ActiveTabBackground** then have no impact on UI.
Also, i tested this behavior with [Showcase](https://github.com/fluentribbon/Fluent.Ribbon/releases/tag/v10.0.4) Ribbon project and result was the same.

I did not found solution for single RibbonTabItem but if you will wrap item in RibbonContextualTabGroup, you will be able to set selected and not selected color for Tab:

```
<Fluent:RibbonContextualTabGroup x:Name="tabGroup1" Header="FIRST" Background="MediumPurple"/>
<Fluent:RibbonTabItem Header="KeyTips"
                ActiveTabBackground="ForestGreen"
                BorderBrush="Aqua"
                Group="{Binding ElementName=tabGroup1, Mode=OneWay}"
                </Fluent:RibbonTabItem>
```

[image]